# What's the quickest way to prune a git tree?

Tags: git, github

I'm looking at my own fork of a very large git (github) repository - with hundreds of old or otherwise uninteresting branches.

I'd like to remove, hide or otherwise not have to deal with, probably, 90% or so of the extra branches. Is there an easy way to edit/prune them, exclusively on my fork?

(Each decision to prune requires interaction with me, so I'm looking for a human-readable interface)

Comment: Delete them from github's branches page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to https://github.com/your-username/your-forked-repo-name/branches/all and delete the branches you don't want.

Then on your local machine, you can run `git remote prune origin` to get rid of the local tracking.

Comment: have you tested this? it gives me a 404

Comment: yeah, it works for me.  Not sure why we would get different results.  Did you edit 'your-username' and 'your-forked-repo-name'?

Comment: yes. getting a 404 with the /all at the end, works fine (well, gives a limited number of branches) without

Comment: Interesting.  The 'all' isn't strictly necessary, I just figured the All branches tab would be less confusing than the Overview branches tab as it would eliminate duplicates and sectioning of branches by activity.